# absolute path in the anchor tag for php function

Tags: php, html, cgi

I have binary which will generate html file. I am trying to call php function in the  tag but it will take the relative path from current file. My code is as below.
cpp file

```
cout<<"<?php"<<endl;
cout<<"if (isset($_GET['function'])){"<<endl;
cout<<"echo 'clicked'";
cout<<"      }"<<endl;
cout<<">"<<endl;

sprintf(retStr,"<u>%s%s%s</u>", "<A HREF=\"?function\">",errorcode.c_str(),"</A>");
cout<<retStr.c_str();
```

Generated php:

```
<?php
 if (isset($_GET['function'])){
echo 'clicked'      }
>
```

Html:

```
<u><A HREF="?function">23427</A></u>
```

I want to call php function from the link, but it will take it as relative path of same binary. When i hover the link it will show `http://localhost/dir/binary?function`
How can I make it take the php function ?

NOTE: I don't have knowledge of php.

Comment: Since this is a php question, not a C++ question, it would probably be a lot easier if you posted formatted PHP code, instead of leaving in the cout statements, which really have nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has error which is generating PHP code it should be as following:

```
cout<<"<?php"<<endl;
cout<<"if (isset($_GET['function'])){"<<endl;
cout<<"echo 'clicked';";
cout<<" }"<<endl;
cout<<"?>"<<endl;
sprintf(retStr,"<u>%s%s%s</u>", "<a href=\"../binary?function\">",errorcode.c_str(),"</a>");
cout<<retStr.c_str();
```

Above code will work for you.

**EDITED:**

```
sprintf(retStr,"<u>%s%s%s</u>", "<a href=\"<?php echo $_REQUEST['SELF'];?>?function\">",errorcode.c_str(),"</a>");
```

Comment: but I don't want to call binary on the click.

Comment: @user3153014 but you cann't do that without calling any path of PHP. or you should call the PHP variable `$_REQUEST['SELF']` add this before `?function` this will work.

Comment: Expected output is it should display "clicked"  on clicking the link, not the same binary

Comment: @CodeLover - so the <a> tags should also be within php tag ?